# InvokeCommand() does not fire

Tags: xamarin.forms, realm, reactiveui

I am using `ReactiveUI` in one of my `Xamarin.Forms` app. It have a `search` functionality. Just like the official sample on ReactiveUI [Github](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI) page. But the `Search command` does not fire when the `query` string changes. I am using realm mobile database for local storage. The View code:

```
  <Shell.TitleView>
    <SearchBar x:Name="SearchHandler"
               Placeholder="Select Company" />
</Shell.TitleView>
<ContentPage.Content>

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="CompaniesListView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                         Margin="10">
                                <Label x:Name="NameLabel"
                                       Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     HeightRequest="1"
                                     Color="BlueViolet" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.Footer>
                <StackLayout Spacing="0"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Frame CornerRadius="20"
                           Margin="10"
                           Padding="0">
                        <Entry Placeholder="Company Name"
                               x:Name="NewCompanyEntry"></Entry>
                    </Frame>

                    <Button Text="Add"
                            x:Name="AddButton"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Footer>
        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

The Code behind:

```
   public partial class MainPage : ReactiveContentPage<MainViewModel>
{


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel = new MainViewModel();


        this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Query, v => v.SearchHandler.Text);
        this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.AddCompanyCommand, v => v.AddButton);
        this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.NewCompany, v => v.NewCompanyEntry.Text);
        this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.Companies, view => view.CompaniesListView.ItemsSource);


    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
 public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
{

    public IEnumerable<Company> Companies { get; set; }


    [Reactive]
    public string Query { get; set; }

    [Reactive]
    public string NewCompany { get; set; }

    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> AddCompanyCommand { get; set; }
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Search { get; set; }

    Realm _realm;

    public MainViewModel()
    {

        _realm = Realm.GetInstance();
        Companies = _realm.All<Company>();

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Query).Select(query => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query)).Select(_ => Unit.Default).Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).InvokeCommand(this, x => x.Search);

        AddCompanyCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async () => await AddButtonClicked());
        Search = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(
            () =>
               Observable
               .StartAsync(SortCollection)
        );
    }



    async Task AddButtonClicked()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NewCompany))
        {
            _realm.Write(() =>
            {
                _realm.Add(new Company { Name = NewCompany });
            });
            NewCompany = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    async Task SortCollection()
    {

        Companies = _realm.All<Company>().OrderBy(m => m.Name).Where(company => company.Name.ToLower().Contains(Query.ToLower()));

    }
}
```

This `demo` app is also available on my [GitHub profile](https://github.com/HobDev/ReactiveUISample).

Thank you.

Comment: Be careful. CreateFromObservable is on a separate thread so for starters your likely to have an exception if it works since binding needs the set of Companies to be done in the main thread. There is a example of this exact scenario in the GitHub readme for ReactiveUI.

Comment: Use the return parameter values of ReactiveCommand and then you can use ToProperty

Comment: Right after WhenAnyValue I assume you’re intending to use a Where statement rather than Select.

Comment: @ColtBauman Oh, I changed that to where. Now I am not getting error on starup. But still unable to search.

Comment: Now accomodating the necessary changes suggested in answer and comments the command is invoked. But the method execution throws RxApp.cs file not found on Android. On iOS the error is in Dispatch.cs file in static void static_dispatcher_to_managed (IntPtr context) method

Comment: Also I don't find any reason to use command parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by Glenn Watson is not complete. Though he helped me through comments and slack to resolve the issue. The complete answer is:

1. Move the Unit.Default select statement to after throttle.
2. Use `Where` instead of `Select` to check if string is `NullOrWhiteSpace`.
3. Move `WhenAnyValue` after where the `command` is created.
4. Finally use MainUIThread to set the Companies from return value of ReactiveCommand.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Query)
    .Select(query => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
    .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .InvokeCommand(this, x => x.Search);
```

This line is likely the issue. Throttle returns a value of the elapsed time. Move the Unit.Default select statement to after it.

Comment: Also move the WhenAnyValue to after where you create the command.

Comment: Also the log output to your debug window can help debug these issues.

Comment: I move the WhenAnyValue after command. Also change the command to CreateFromTask. But now I am getting RxApp.cs file not found exception at runtime. The app builds without any error.

Comment: This is the gist of my application output https://gist.github.com/HobDev/4d247e9d144f9e0ea449e59557fdcb31, if that can help in any way. Thank you

Comment: Is it necessary to pass parameter and return result from the ReactiveCommand. In my scenario I don't feel the need to do so. I can get the query string from viewmodel and set the companies in the method.

Comment: See my comment above. It'll be fun from a seperate thread which the UI won't allow. Returning it will put the result onto the main thread again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197470/discussion-between-hobby-dev-and-glenn-watson).